# Sacrificing a creature you don't own but you control

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I use a [Thief of Sanity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThief%20of%20Sanity%5d) and exile a [Kroxa, Titan of Death's Hunger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKroxa%2c%5d%2b%5bTitan%5d%2b%5bof%5d%2b%5bDeath%27s%5d%2b%5bHunger%5d) from my opponent's deck. I cast Kroxa, but then of course would have to sacrifice it because it wasn't escaped. Would it go back into my opponent's graveyard or mine? Am I able to escape it without the correct mana still?

Comment: I believe that since @Swong is a new contributor, the question can be left here. Moreover (and much more important than the previous argument),the game dynamics that is presented here is, in my opinion, very different too, because Swong asks if it is possible to use the escape ability when a card is in exile,in order to understand properly a situation like that one. All this does not concern the other question, the one to which Doppelgreener refers as a duplicate.

Comment: @ManoFromBerlin: Closing a duplicate question isn't a punishment - it's just the appropriate way to keep work from being duplicated while still answering the question (since anyone can view the linked question), so there's no reason to avoid doing it for a new user. And both questions are about sacrifice - even though the other question is sacrificing for a different reason, they're close enough and the answers there apply word-for-word here so there's no reason to leave this open.

Comment: (The second question is different, but it would be nice to have that as it's own question with an appropriate title that would let users find it, rather than buried in a duplicate question about sacrifice.)

Comment: To prevent the original application from being "buried",as congruent with the linked one, it would be sufficient to adequately edit its title and highlighting the Escape ability, rather than highlighting that it is a duplicate. I would like to know if @Swong agrees with what is claimed, and on the duplication of his question ... In any case, Miles Budnek has done well to answer the question, to clarify how to behave in a similar situation, especially concerning the Escape ability: what is not found in the linked question.

Answer (score 5):

**Kroxa will be put into its owner's graveyard.**

> 400.3. If an object would go to any library, graveyard, or hand other than its owner’s, it goes to its owner’s corresponding zone.

So if you cast your opponent's [Kroxa, Titan of Death's Hunger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKroxa%2c%5d%2b%5bTitan%5d%2b%5bof%5d%2b%5bDeath%27s%5d%2b%5bHunger%5d) using your [Thief of Sanity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThief%20of%20Sanity%5d) you will have to sacrifice it, since it wasn't cast using escape, and it will be put into your opponent's graveyard.

---

Additionally, even if Kroxa *was* put into your graveyard, you would have to pay {B}{B}{R}{R} to escape it.

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. There are nine exceptions to this rule:

None of the exceptions are relevant in this case.  That means that as soon as you cast Kroxa using the Thief of Sanity's ability the Thief's ability loses track of Kroxa and its effect that allows you to spend mana of any type to cast the Kroxa no longer applies.